# Any hint on : Every $A_{n}$ elemnt is $n$-cycles product.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

[Added explanation]
I found this exercise as follows in Hungerford : Abstract algebra (3rd edition) page 236, exercise number 40. Stated as follows :

> C.40.  Prove that every element of $A_{n}$ is a product of $n$-cycles.

$n$-cycle is explained in the book like the permutation : $(1 2 3 4 ....n)$

[Original text]

Every $A_{n}$ element is a product of $n$-cycles .
Tried everything i could imagine, though got further, could not find a solution
How could i prove it? A hint is what i am looking for. 
$A_{n}$ : The Alternating group , the subgroup of the group of permutations $S_{n}$ in a set of $n$ elements.

Comment: What you wrote is not clear. Do you mean, *"Every element of $A_n$ is a product of $n$-cycles"*?

Comment: see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/what-do-all-the-k-cycles-in-s-n-generate)

Comment: @ZevChonoles That wouldn't make sense when $n$ is even because $n$-cycles are not in $A_n$. I haven't a clue what is being asked!

Comment: But a product of $n$-cycles might just be in $A_{n}$.  Like $(1234)(1234)=(13)(24)$ is in $A_{n}$, but $(1234)$ is not.

Comment: Yes that's true! Well the $n$-cycles generate a normal subgroup of $S_n$, so you could use the fact that for $n \ge 5$ the only such subgroups are $1$, $A_n$, and $S_n$.

Comment: Very good start, but "normal group" , and your fact are not known to me , yet.

Comment: If you multiply $(1,2,3,\ldots,n)$  by the inverse of $(2,1,3,\ldots,n)$ then you get a $3$-cycle. Does that help?

Comment: ..And $3$-cycles generates $A_{n}$. Perfect. Case closed !